# How do I tell VBA code to try again on a specific error?

Tags: vba, error-handling

I have some code which occasionally errors (if someone makes a change in the DB whilst I am trying to read as our locking is set to table level rather than row level and I can't change this).

When it errors I hit debug and then hit continue and it continues on its merry way.

Is it possible on this error only to replicate my actions?

```
On Error Resume next
```

will skip over the erroring command and continue on, I don't want this, I want to continue with the command that gave the error as it usually works. However if the error is persistent then there could be a wider issue and we should stop.

I am thinking maybe an error trapping routine which then checks the error code and if it's a match it resumes (not Resume Next), if not then alert the user. Does this sound like the right way?

I have knocked this UNTESTED code up as I am not overly in bed with errors and error handling as I usually build my code to not error but in this case it is out of my control.

```
ErrHandler:
If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
    ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1 'This is set to 0 at the start of the code
    If ErrorCount > 5 Then
        MsgBox "5 Rowfetch errors occured, could be a wider issue"
        End
    End If
    Resume
End If
Err.Raise 'I Think this is wrong, how do I raise an error as VBA normally would?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
ErrHandler:
If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
    ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
    If ErrorCount > 5 Then
        MsgBox "5 Rowfetch errors occured, could be a wider issue"
        End
    End If
    MsgBox "Stopped the error: " & ErrorCount 'In for testing to prove the error happened and was avoided
    Resume
End If
Err.Raise Err.Number
```

This was the part I was not getting right:

```
Err.Raise Err.Number
```